# Image Listview - pass drawable location with intent to next activity

Tags: android, image, listview, android-intent, drawable

I have ExpandableListView with images and when clicked on child, it opens this same image in new activity.

I fail to "grab" the location of drawable (for example R.drawable.twitter) when passing it with intent, so if you could explain me what to **insert** myIntent.putExtra("image", **here**); I would be really grateful!

**Array list:**

```
  ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
  Country country = new Country("Where do I sign", R.drawable.twitter, "Tom Cruise", "TOP GUN");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new Country("Count me in", R.drawable.facebook, "Jonah Hill", "21 JUMP STREET");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new Country("Show me the money", R.drawable.facebook, "Tom  Cruise", "JERRY MAGUIRE");
  countryList.add(country);

  Continent continent = new Continent("Yes",countryList);
  continentList.add(continent);

  countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
  country = new Country("I cant' do that", R.drawable.facebook, "Robert De Niro", "GOODFELLAS");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new Country("Forget about it", R.drawable.facebook, "Johny Deep", "DONIE BRASCO");
  countryList.add(country);
  country = new Country("You have no power here", R.drawable.facebook, "Bernard Hill", "LORD OF THE RINGS");
  countryList.add(country);

  continent = new Continent("No",countryList);
  continentList.add(continent);
```

**Country class:**

```
 public class Country {

 private String code = "";
 private int Image;
 private String actor = "";
 private String movie = "";

 public Country(String code, int Image, String actor, String movie) {
  super();
  this.code = code;
  this.Image = Image;
  this.actor = actor;
  this.movie = movie;
 }

 public String getCode() {
  return code;
 }
 public void setCode(String code) {
  this.code = code;
 }
 public int getImage() {
        return Image;
 }

 public void setImage(int Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
 }

 public String getActor() {
      return actor;
     }
 public void setActor(String actor) {
      this.actor = actor;
     }

 public String getMovie() {
      return movie;
         }
 public void setMovie(String movie) {
      this.movie = movie;
         }  
}
```

**Intent activity A:**

```
 myList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3, long arg4) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("image", ------);

        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        return false;
    }
 });
```

**getIntent Activity B:**

```
 Intent myIntent = getIntent();

int image = myIntent.getIntExtra("image", 0);

ImageView imagefull = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imagefull.setImageResource(image);
```

Comment: you just need to use the position to grab the image, just look for examples in google: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`myIntent.putExtra("image", myList.get(position).getImage());`

And then use it as such in the getIntentActivity.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I've tried it before, I get "The method get(int) is undefined for the type ExpandableListView"

Comment: change the position with arg3 in your code. I didnt noticed earlier

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Works like this: 
myIntent.putExtra("image", ((Country) listAdapter.getChild(arg2, arg3)).getImage());